# I'm having trouble moving the music from my External Hard drive to my new Laptop?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, itunes

I've had, for a long time now, all of my music on my external hard drive, plugged into my desktop. Now I have a new laptop that I want to place the music on. I plugged in the Hard drive and the folder with all of my music pops up, but for some reason, on the laptop, it says "folder empty". In the properties it says that the folder has 44GB, but when I click into the folder it reads empty. This is not the case for my desktop. what gives?

Answer (score 0):

What operating system is on your laptop? Could it be that for some reason the music is 'hidden' and that's why you can't see it on your laptop? To display hidden content (on Windows), go to the folder, press `Alt+t` -> `Folder options` -> `View` -> `Show hidden files, folders, and drives`.